# I want to write a C program to add an arbitrary list of numbers given by user...can anyone fix this program?

Tags: c

I want to write a C program to add the numbers given by the user as long as they want... can anyone fix this program?

I tried to use a do-while loop.
Any other suggestions to improve my code?
I am unable to end the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x=0, sum = 0, y=0, fu;

    printf("first number you want to add:\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    printf("next number you want to add:\n");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    x=x+y;


    do
    {
        printf("do you want to add numbers further? \nEnter 0:Yes or 1:No: \n");
        scanf("%d", &fu);
        printf("next number you want to add:\n");
        scanf("%d", &y);
        x=x+y;
    }
    while(fu>0);

        sum=x;

    printf("Sum of all integers = %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to check the return value from `scanf()` to ensure it successfully read a number (and should take appropriate action if it didn't).  Making the user type two numbers for every number to be added is not a great interface.  It would be more orthodox to read up to end of file (or an error).  I also note that you ask "do you want to continue" and get an answer and then ignore what the user says.  That's not polite.

Comment: Run it in a debugger.  It will be clear then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask for the 3rd and further numbers in an `if` and modify your `while`:

```
scanf("%d", &fu);
    if(fu == 0) {
        printf("next number you want to add:\n");
        scanf("%d", &y);
        x=x+y;
    }
}
while(fu == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your prompt says:

> Enter 0:Yes or 1:No:

so you need to continue that loop if `0` was entered:

```
while(fu == 0);
```

Also, you don't need to take another `y` after non-`0` input.

Answer (score 0):

The key to taking any input, either from the user, or from a file, is to validate every single input by ***checking the return***. You cannot blindly use a variable holding input until you know whether the input succeeded or failed. Otherwise, if the input fails and you use a variable whose value is indeterminate, you invoke *undefined behavior*.

Also, if you are using a formatted input function such as `scanf()`, if a *matching failure* occurs, character extraction from `stdin` ceases at that point and the characters causing the failure are left in `stdin` -- unread, just waiting to bite you again on your next attempted input.

Instead, if you use a line-oriented input function such as `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()`, you read an entire line at a time. You can simply call `sscanf()` on the buffer filled by `fgets()` to convert a numeric input to an integer value. That way it does not matter if the conversion succeeds or fails, you do not leave anything unread in the input stream.

Just as you must validate every input, you so too must validate every conversion. Whether using `sscanf()` or `strtol()`, etc... a failure to validate every conversion will likely lead to *undefined behavior* when you fail to detect the conversion failure.

Another benefit of using `fgets()` or `getline()` is they read and store the `'\n'` from the user pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. So rather than having to prompt `"do you want to add numbers further? \nEnter 0:Yes or 1:No: \n"` and have to worry about yet another input and conversion -- you simply check if <kbd>Enter</kbd> was pressed on an empty line to know the user completed input (e.g. the first character in the buffer filed by `fgets()` is the `'\n'` character).

You also have to handle an invalid input correctly. What if the user enters `"bananas"` instead of a number?

Putting it altogether, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1024           /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {
    
    char buf[MAXC];         /* buffer (character array) to hold all user input */
    int sum = 0, n = 0;     /* sum and count of numbers */
    
    puts ("press ENTER alone to exit:\n");      /* display instructions */
    while (1) {                                 /* loop continually */
        int tmp;                                /* temporary int to add to sum */
        /* prompt based on 1st or subsequent number */
        fputs (n ? "next number  : " : "first number : ", stdout);
        /* read and validate input, break on EOF or empty line */
        if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin) || *buf == '\n') {
            puts ("---------------------");
            break;
        }
        /* validate conversion to int */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &tmp) == 1) {    /* on success */
            sum += tmp;                         /* add to sum */
            n += 1;                             /* increment count */
        }
        else    /* handle error */
            fputs ("  error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
    }
    
    printf ("         sum : %d\n", sum);        /* output final sum */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/sum
press ENTER alone to exit:

first number : 10
next number  : -20
next number  : 30
next number  : -40
next number  : bananas
  error: invalid integer input.
next number  : 50
next number  :
---------------------
         sum : 30
```

There are several ways to approach this, and if you wanted the user to be able to enter more than one-number per-line, you could parse `buf` with `strtol()` to extract all values. (you can do the same with `sscanf()` using an offset from the beginning of the string and the characters consumed on each conversion from the `"%n"` specifier) Many ways to go.

Let me know if you have further questions.